# Find the number of divisors of (N!)^2

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I am trying to solve the [following problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equations), which I reduced to the:
**find the number of divisors of (N!)^2**

I coded up my solution, which I included as an answer here (for the reason of not being accused of not doing any work), and it works properly and fast for even big numbers, but because it does not pass all the tests due to the timeout, I think that my algorithm is not so efficient.

Here is outline of my idea:

1. Any number can be presented as `a0^b1*a1^b1*...*an^bn` which will have `(1 + b1)*(1 + b2)*...*(1 + bn)` divisors
2. then `M^2` will have `(1 + 2b1)*(1 + 2b2)*...*(1 + 2bn)` divisors
3. create a function which finds all factors of the number and save them as a hashmap
4. have a function which will combine two hashmaps by adding the values of corresponding keys
5. use these 2 functions to iterate through all the numbers from 2 to n to get all divisors of factorial
6. use the function from 1. to get the answer

I thought that this solution is pretty efficient, but it looks like there is a better way.
Can anyone suggest me a better way?

Comment: For such problems you might find better answers on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Vektor88 I thought about it and also about code-review, but I believe that this is a better place.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I really think that when it's matter of performance, or complexity, CS is a better place. But it's just an advice. You surely know and use this site more then me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question has an easy and efficient solution. Note that `n!` is:

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 * 8 * ... * n
```

Let's think about how many times a prime factor appears in this product, for example `2`.
It appears once every `2` factors. But once every `4` factors it appears twice. And once every `8` factors it appears thrice etc.
In other words the factor `2` will appear in `n!` `sum(n//(2**e) for e in range(1, n))` times. The same is true for any prime factor `k`.

You can implement this computation with:

```
import itertools as it

def exp_for_factor_in_factorial(factor, n):
    total = 0
    for e in it.count(1):
        if factor ** e > n:
            break
        total += n // factor**e
    return total
```

Now, in order to find all prime factors of `n!` we need to find all primes up to `n`, which is easily done using eratosthenes:

```
import math

def sieve(n):
    nums = [True] * (n+1)
    nums[:2] = [False]*2
    nums[4::2] = [False] * math.ceil((n-3)/2)
    for i in range(3, int((n+1)**.5)+1, 2):
        if nums[i]:
            for j in range(i*i, n+1, 2*i):
                nums[j] = False
    return [i for i,k in enumerate(nums) if k]
```

And this allows us to obtain the factorization of `n!`:

```
def get_factorization_factorial(n):
    primes = sieve(n)
    factors = []
    for p in primes:
        factors.append((p, exp_for_factor_in_factorial(p, n)))
    return factors
```

Finally, to compute the number of divisors from a factorization you can use the formula you already mentioned:

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def get_num_divisors(factorization):
    return reduce(op.mul, (e+1 for _, e in factorization), 1)
```

And so the final answer can be obtained as:

```
def divs_of_squared_fact(n):
    return get_num_divisors((p, 2*e) for p, e in get_factorization_factorial(n))
```

Note that this solution is extremely more performant than yours:

```
In [41]: %%timeit
    ...: for i in range(2, 1000):
    ...:     x = divs_of_squared_fact(i)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 276 ms per loop

In [42]: %%timeit
    ...: for i in range(2, 1000):
    ...:     x = divisorsOfFactorialSquare(i)
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 7.89 s per loop
```

It is able to produce the number of divisors of `(5000!)^2` in about `2ms`, while the other one takes almost half a second:

```
In [47]: %timeit divs_of_squared_fact(5000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.07 ms per loop

In [48]: %timeit divisorsOfFactorialSquare(5000)
1 loops, best of 3: 439 ms per loop
```

Well, in fact the answers have different asymptotic complexity so the difference goes to infinity when increasing the argument.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to write this detailed explanation. Explanation and implementation is excellent.